# line messenger share button with description

Tags: url, socialshare, line.me

I want to share url using line messenger and adding some text description before I click share button, I did'nt find source for adding some description for social share button using line messenger. I just found this for share button using url for line messenger, you can read in this [link](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#lineme), it's very helpfull for me, but I still want to add some description. I already read developer guide for line messenger in https://developers.line.me/ but did'nt find what I want, can anybody tell me is that possible for adding description for socual share button using url ?